# How we can we format Text as superscript or subscript in Android Jetpack Compose UI?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I am working on one example using [Android Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/), where I am displaying some text equations like below :

```
<html>
<body>

<!-- Superscript-->
<p> E = mc<sup>2</sup></p>

<!--Subscript-->
<p> CH<sub>4</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O = CO + 3H<sub>2</sub></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Does there any decoration or style mechanism exist for Text that I can use to achieve the same output?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define a [**`SpanStyle`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/SpanStyle) using the [**`BaselineShift.Superscript`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/BaselineShift#superscript) and [**`BaselineShift.Subscript`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/BaselineShift#superscript).

Something like:

```
    val superscript = SpanStyle(
        baselineShift = BaselineShift.Superscript,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        color = Color.Red
    )
    val subscript = SpanStyle(
        baselineShift = BaselineShift.Subscript,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        color = Color.Blue
    )
```

Then you can use the [**`AnnotatedString`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString) to display the
text with multiple styles.

Something like:

```
Text(
    fontSize = 20.sp,
    text = buildAnnotatedString {
        append("E = mc")
        withStyle( superscript) {
            append("2")
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

and

```
    Text(
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        text = buildAnnotatedString {
            append("CH")
            withStyle( subscript) {
                append("4")
            }
            append(" + H")
            withStyle( subscript) {
                append("2")
            }
            append("O = CO + 3H")
            withStyle( subscript) {
                append("2")
            }
        }
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

**UPDATE:** Please refer new answer mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66801935/2949612

---

Using [BaselineShift](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/BaselineShift), we can use [Span](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/core/package-summary#span) for Text widget, which allows to decorate text as subscript or superscript.

Below is the working code to achieve the above output:

```
    @Composable
    fun Equations(name: String) {
    val defaultStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp,
            color = Color.White)
    val scriptStyleSuper = TextStyle(
            baselineShift = BaselineShift.Superscript,
            fontSize = 12.sp,
            color = Color.Green)
    val scriptStyleSub = TextStyle(
            baselineShift = BaselineShift.Subscript,
            fontSize = 12.sp,
            color = Color.Green)
    Text {
        Span(text = "E = mc", style = defaultStyle) {
            Span(
                    text = "2",
                    style =scriptStyleSuper
            ) {
                Span(text = "\n")
                Span(text = "CH", style = defaultStyle)
                Span(text = "4 ",style = scriptStyleSub)
                Span(text = "+ H", style = defaultStyle)
                Span(text = "2",style = scriptStyleSub)
                Span(text = "O = CO + 3H", style = defaultStyle)
                Span(text = "2",style = scriptStyleSub)
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image: jetpack compose baseline shift]

To check more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/package-summary

Comment: What library is Span part of?

Comment: @BrillPappin Span class has been deprecated. Please refer new answer to achieve same https://stackoverflow.com/a/66801935/2949612

Answer (score 0):

Please use unicode directly, for every symbol you will be able to find one unicode.